# how to make sound-associated-objects enter stage randomly one at a time and when destroyed by a bullet should again reappear [as3]

Tags: actionscript-3

I am only three months old as far as my knowledge on AS3 or programming in general is concerned.But anyhow with lots of struggle and sleepless nights i have completed three levels of creating an Alphabet Learning App.

In the fourth and the final level i wish to create a small game where movie clips associated with a particular alphabet-pronunciation mp3 will randomly enter the stage horizontally and approach a particular target. Before this audio-object hits the target, the player has to click the correct alphabet Movie Clip laid out on the lower half of the stage. If the player goes and clicks on the right alphabet icon as the fly-in audio-object eg., if an mp3 which pronounces "a" is flying into the stage and approaching the target and the player goes and immediately clicks on the Alphabet "A" icon laid out on the lower half of the stage, it is as if like the target has fired a bullet against the enemy mp3 fly-in object and has destroyed it.

If the player mistakenly goes and keeps on clicking on some wrong Alphabet icon like "R" or "O" then the fly-in mp3 object approaches and hits the target and the player loses a turn. The basic idea is to test how efficient the child-learner is in associating "alphabet pronunciation audio clips" to the "corresponding alphabet icon".

Please pardon me for my lengthy explanation. Also, to kindly remind, i have no idea whatsoever about Object Oriented Programming so please avoid OOP approach and terminology...thnx in advance.

Comment: get some formatting into your question. noone likes to read wall of text

Comment: There is going to be a lot of coding involved with this project, and tons more without the use of OOP. I would suggest embracing OOP, it can only help in the long run.

Comment: Jonny i appreciate your advice but then since i have already got a long way in starting with this project i just wish to complete it using  the conventional non-OOP approach. After this project i will definitely start learning OOP in as3..for now, can u kindly give some guidelines on how i can complete this task.

Comment: What you could do is add every letter to the stage, give them instance names, set their visibility to false, and reposition them and set them visible one at a time when needed. If you have some code i can help you edit it

Comment: hello marton thnx for your willingness to help...can u pls give me ur mail id...